# Como fazer o LinearLayout ficar na parte inferior da tela?

Tags: java, android

Eu já tentei aqui muitas coisas para fazer meu LinearLayout ficar no rodapé da tela mas não consigo fazer isso.
Eu preciso fazer isso com o Linear que tem o id= "embaixo"
Alguém sabe?

Segue meu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="Teste"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="+id/embaixo"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/marca_simplifica" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Olá @Aline, já cogitou usar pesos ? Caso não sirvam, você pode colcoar o linearlayout dentro de um relativelayout e jogar ele pra parte inferior.

Comment: Como???????? Vou tentar fazer aqqui

Comment: Conseguiu fazer Aline ? Dei uma resposta abaixo, talvez sirva como exemplo para o seu problema

Comment: Consegui. Mas eu como iniciante entendi mais a outra resposta...a sua eu achei meio complicada..........desculpe.......

Comment: Ah é bem simples haha digamos que ali eu tenho 2 linearlayout dentro de um relativelayout, um irá ficar na parte superior e outra na parte inferior da tela

Comment: Ah entendi agora Matheus :)

Comment: Daqui a pouco vou fazer outra pergunta Matheus...Pq eu to com problemas para fazer o botão voltar em um TabLayout... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os linearlayout digamos que respeitam uma hierarquia, se eles estão na horizontal então eles irão ser alocados um ao lado do outro, se estão na vertical serão alocados um embaixo do outro. A ordem fica de acordo com o XML.
Os relativelayout, digamos que quebram esse padrão e você consegue adaptar outros layouts de acordo com sua necessidade.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de como colocar um linearlayout em cima e um embaixo em um relativelayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_linear_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_linear_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve incluir o **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**, mas para que o mesmo funcione, tem que ser filho de um `RelativeLayout` exemplo:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
             android:id="+id/embaixo"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true
             android:gravity="end"
             android:padding="10dp"
             android:background="@color/colorAccent"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

             ...            

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Essa resposta funciona também mas é necessário colocar o LinearLayout dentro de um RelativeLayout. :)